# How do I build backlinks?

Tags: seo, backlinks

I've recently made a site and I want to know how to go about making backlinks?

Comment: "i'm still not referrenced by google" - actually Google is aware of about 793 results from your domain: http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asunshinetrekking.com

Comment: How do you build backlinks?  Carefully.

Comment: I have implemented an online checklist for unnatural links: http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/unnatural-links-checklist.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Good answer:**

The best way to get backlinks, especially quality backlinks, is to have high quality content on your website. These naturally attract links as webmasters prefer to link to good content and not frivolous content.

**Not so good answer:**

- <s>Place your link in forum signatures</s>
- <s>Submit to directories</s>
- <s>Exchange links</s>
- <s>Comment on blogs</s>
- <s>Submit articles to article directories with your links in them</s>

These links will be low quality and not do you as much good as links from established websites that rank well for the keywords you wish to rank well for. But if you want to build up *quantity* of links then these will help to do it.

(Make sure any links you get are not "nofollow" or else they will essentially worthless from a SEO point of view. And don't spam other websites. Nobody likes a spammer).

Comment: Well my site is related to travel. So including travel tips will help it?

Comment: Very definitely.

Comment: Nofollow links are not worthless.  They don't convey page rank, but they do bring traffic and possibly help get other links.  My most successful blog post is where it is thanks to a single nofollow link that brought real people, not bots to my site.

Answer (score 3):

There are hundreds of ways to build back links.  To get your site started you should really do this:

1. Register you site on [DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org/).
2. Setup a [Google Webmaster Account](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) and add your website.  This tells Google you exist.
3. Make your content as good as possible.  This will make you move up in SERP.  Google really cares about quality.
4. Setup a Twitter account, Facebook account, etc and post links to specific pages to get link backs.  This can help your Page Rank and help where you show up in SERP but 1 and 2 will help you with Google.

Answer (score 2):

We have two good answers here.

But there is one obvious one that it is not, may be to be so obvious: ask other sites to link back.

Check over the web what are good related sites to yours, make a list of interesting ones, send an email to administrators/moderators asking to include an article or just a link about/for your site.

If you have quality content, they probably will link back. Keep a tracking of this link building. For who you asked, when you asked, when they replyed, do they have any questions...? Follow up with that.

It is simple, quick, and worth much more than people usually imagine. You need just a browser, a spreadsheet, an email, and a dose of good writing, being polite.

Answer (score 0):

Post your website to delicious bookmarks and other bookmarking websites, it will not give you any pagerank but might make get your noticed by the Google Bot faster.

There is also a slight chance that your website is in the [Google Sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_effect), if it is - then with some time you will get out and get noticed.

To be certain that Google Bot is actually visiting your website (even if you are not indexed), check the server logs of your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Before wasting your time or paying someone to waste it for you in building useless link campaigns, I strongly suggest you to read [Virtuosi Media smart consideration about link building](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/tool-or-online-service-to-view-google-pr-of-thousand-sites-from-a-list/2446#2446).

**Link building by hand (one by one) is a huge effort**. Almost all blogs/forums/social network uses NOFOLLOW link which make those links completely useless for increase Google rank.

1. you need to find the blogs/directories/forums out there that do **not use NOFOLLOW** in links and that have pages containing keywords related to your site contents.
   **This might take you a huge amount of time** if you want to insert 100 links in 100 different sites.
2. But let's suppose you already have a 'SEO' list of blogs/directories/forums that do not use NOFOLLOW. In order to insert a link you have to go through all the registration processes (in forum/directory, and nowadays also in some blogs) and verifying the email address on each registration etc.
   This might end up in taking you more than 15 minutes for each link. **100 link at 15min each will take you 25 hours of work only to insert the links.**

**1 + 2 = couple of weeks (or more) of full time work for 100 GOOD links.** And maybe after few months your site will rank just couple of positions higher in Google than before.